# AngularJS Better way to share functionality between controllers when $scope is involved?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm pretty new using angular, and I don't know what's the best way to share functionality between controllers when the scope is involved (in other situations I understand that the solution is to create a service).

I've write a jsfiddle with two possibles solutions, but I'm not convinced with any of them:

http://jsfiddle.net/zemogc/LQ59p/

The example consists in showing a message with a certain type. In the example message and type is given by the form (deppending on button is called a soution or another), but in my app there'll be many controllers in many diferent pages that will could show a message (and the message div will be included with ng-include) so I've created a function called ManageMessage in two different ways:

- ManageMessage Service. It works, but a I need pass the $scope as a variable. Not very pretty.

```
    $scope.changeMessageService = function (messageText, messageType){
        ManageMessage.set($scope, messageText, messageType);
    };
```

- ManageMessageCtrl. It works too, but i need to call $controller method from the MainCtrl, passing the scope as variable too. I've searching the use of $controller and I found that is used especially in test cases so this solution don't convince me too.

```
    $scope.changeMessageController = function (messageText, messageType) {
        $scope.message = messageText;
        $scope.messageType = messageType;
        $controller('ManageMessageCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    };
```

So what will be the best way to implement the ManageMessage to be used form different controllers? (Now I ask a specific question, but my problem is generic and i try to resume it in the title).

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is not good.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I would recommend separating the `status` from the `$scope`.  So, the idea would be to design like this:

**statusService.js**:

```
angular.module('app').factory('statusService', [function() {

   return {
      getStatus: function(messageType) {

         status = {};  // could set some defaults here
         switch (messageType) {
            case 'error':
                status.isOk = false;
                status.isLoading = false;
                status.isError = true;
                status.noMessage = false;
                break;
            case 'ok':
                status.isOk = true;
                status.isLoading = false;
                status.isError = true;
                status.noMessage = false;
                break;

            case 'loading':
                status.isOk = false;
                status.isLoading = true;
                status.isError = false;
                status.noMessage = false;
                break;
            case 'none':
                status.message = '';
                status.noMessage = true;
                break;
        }

        return status;
      }
   }
}]);
```

**controllers**:

```
myAppControllers.controller('ManageMessageCtrl', ['$scope', 'statusService', function ($scope, statusService) {
    if ($scope.message === '') {
        $scope.messageType = 'none';
    }

    var status = statusService.getStatus($scope.messageType);

    $scope.isOk = status.isOk;
    $scope.isLoading = status.isLoading;
    $scope.isError = status.isError;
    $scope.noMessage = status.noMessage;
    $scope.message = status.message;    

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Davin, it's a good point to improve ManageMessageCtrl. So, do you validate the use of $controller to call ManageMessageCtrl from MainCtrl? (this was the principal question/doubt).